# border radios of text BackgroundColor

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want this text to have a background-color with border radios

```
Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(120, 247, 158, 1),
        borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.circular(15)),
    child: new Text(
      exe[index]['name'],
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 15,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),//Text
  ),//container
```

this is the output 
[image]

but I want the background_Color of the Text to automatically have the length of the text and no more. how can I do this?

Comment: I test your code, and I see exactly what you are asking for! So I guess other parent Widget is causing this container to strech. Maybe a Column with CrossAxisAlignment.stretch or something. Post a little more code to see your problem.

Comment: yes, your answer is true thanks. now if I want my backgroundColor to have a bit more length than my text what should I do? @encubos

Comment: Enclouse your Text() widget with a Padding(). Example: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10, right:10, top:4, bottom:4), child: Text( ... ),)